# Why is this php not working?

Tags: php, html, file, addition

```
<?php
if ( isset( $_POST['1'] ) ) {
    $file = 'count.txt';
    $current_count = file_get_contents( 'count.txt' ); 
    file_put_contents($file,str_replace($current_count,$current_count + 1,file_get_contents($file)));
    $handle = fopen( 'count.txt', 'w' ); 
    fwrite( $current_count, $handle ); 
    fclose( $handle );
}
?>
```

I am trying to make a simple counter. When i press a button, it takes me to this php file, with that code. The code SHOULD read what's inside count.txt, the number "1", and replace it with 2, which is one plus one. For some reason, this is not working. I am probably doing something wrong. Please help me discover my mistake or an alternate way to do it. I need to restate that a button links directly to this php script, so I may not need the $_POST.

Comment: use file_put_contents OR fwrite, not both, currently the latter will be overwriting the former

Comment: @Dagon it still isnt working. I deleted the last three lines, starting from "$handle" down.

Comment: in what way is it "not working" ?

Comment: @Dagon it does not give the intended result. I still have the number 1 in count.txt

Comment: Did you check the permissions of the file?

Comment: @Anonymous yea i have permission

Comment: Try `file_put_contents($file,$current_count + 1);` instead and make sure that `$_POST['1']` is actually set.  Also, are you sure that you tried without the last three lines?

Answer (score 0):

This is tested and works

```
<?php

if ( isset( $_POST['1'] ) ) {
    $file = 'count.txt';
    $current_count = file_get_contents($file);
    $current_count++;
    file_put_contents($file, $current_count);
} else {
    die("Post Not Set");
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This is because of how you are doing this.  In a nutshell, you are getting the count out of the file, storing it in $current_count, writing the file with an incremented count, clobbering the file, and finally writing the original count back to the file.

```
if ( isset( $_POST['1'] ) ) {
    $file = 'count.txt';
    // At this point, $current_count will be 1
    $current_count = file_get_contents( 'count.txt' ); 

    // $current_count will still be 1 after this line.  
    // It is not incremented. The file will have a 2 
    // in it though as you are writing what $current_count + would be.
    file_put_contents($file,str_replace($current_count,$current_count + 1,file_get_contents($file)));

    // File gets clobbered(emptied) by opening it with a 'w'.
    $handle = fopen( 'count.txt', 'w' ); 

    // You then write a 1 right back to the file, because 
    // that is what $current_count is equal to.
    fwrite( $current_count, $handle ); 
    fclose( $handle );
}
```

The least that you need is this:

```
 <?php
     $file = 'count.txt';

     $current_count = file_get_contents( 'count.txt' );
     file_put_contents($file,str_replace($current_count,$current_count + 1,file_get_contents($file)));
 ?>
```

Comment: sorry to be an a**, but it doesnt have a two in it. I was wondering if i could possibly take out the $_POST, reread the original question if you dont get why. If it cannot be removed, what should the post value be, should it stay as ['1']?

Comment: Really... Re-read your question. Re-read my answer.  You are writing the file twice in your original code - once with an incremented value and once with the original value.

Comment: i said that because i edited the question. I fully understand your answer and it is very useful but it is still not working (count.txt is the same). I dont not know why.